# Tarda el mostrar mas de 5000 registros angularjs y c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, mvc

estoy intentando mostrar 5000 registros y estoy usando angularjs y c# mvc5 si me muestra todos los registros en el datatable solo que tarda en mostrarlos, que puedo hacer para optimizar esto y no tarde tanto, cabe mencionar que en la consola si muestra los registros al momento de cargar la pagina solo tarda al momento de mostrarlos en el html o datatable

controller.js

```
$http.get("Home/getMedidores").success(function (res) { 
        $scope.medidores = res.data;
        console.log($scope.medidores)
    })
```

controlador c#

```
 public ActionResult getMedidores()
    {
        string sucursal = Convert.ToString(Session["Sucursal"]);
        if (sucursal == "Todas")
        {
            var data = db.Medidors.Where(x => x.activo == true).Select
                (z => new
                {
                    NumeroEconomico = z.num_economico,
                    Serie = z.serie,
                    Holograma = z.holograma,
                    Sello = z.sello,
                    Cuenta = z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.cuenta).FirstOrDefault() == null ? "No disponible" :
                    z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.cuenta).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Zona = z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.zona).FirstOrDefault() == null ? "No disponible" :
                    z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.zona).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Direccion = z.Transaccions.Where
                    (v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select(c => c.catCuenta.direccionPadron).FirstOrDefault()
                    == null ? "No disponible" : z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.direccionPadron).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Marca = z.Marca.marca1,
                    Modelo = z.Modelo.modelo1,
                    Capacidad = z.Capacidad.capacidad1,
                    Electrocorrector = z.Electrocorrector.num_electro
                    == null ? "No disponible" : SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)z.Electrocorrector.num_electro).Trim(),
                    Status = z.Status.status1,
                    FechaMovimiento = z.fecha_movimiento.ToString()
                }).OrderBy(x => x.Zona).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            var data = db.Medidors.Where(x => x.activo == true && x.Sucursal.nombre == sucursal).Select
                (z => new
                {
                    NumeroEconomico = z.num_economico,
                    Serie = z.serie,
                    Holograma = z.holograma,
                    Sello = z.sello,
                    Cuenta = z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.cuenta).FirstOrDefault() == null ? "No disponible" :
                    z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.cuenta).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Zona = z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.zona).FirstOrDefault() == null ? "No disponible" :
                    z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.zona).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Direccion = z.Transaccions.Where
                    (v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select(c => c.catCuenta.direccionPadron).FirstOrDefault()
                    == null ? "No disponible" : z.Transaccions.Where(v => v.id_medidor == z.id_medidor).Select
                    (c => c.catCuenta.direccionPadron).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Marca = z.Marca.marca1,
                    Modelo = z.Modelo.modelo1,
                    Capacidad = z.Capacidad.capacidad1,
                    Electrocorrector = z.Electrocorrector.num_electro == null ? "No disponible" : SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)z.Electrocorrector.num_electro).Trim(),
                    Status = z.Status.status1,
                    FechaMovimiento = z.fecha_movimiento
                }).OrderBy(x => x.Zona).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

html

```
<div class="text-center m-t-lg" ng-controller="MedidoresController">
                        <h1>
                        </h1>
                        <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions"  class="table  table-condensed table-hover dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Numero Economico</th>
                                    <th>Serie</th>
                                    <th>Holograma</th>
                                    <th>Sello</th>
                                    <th>Cuenta</th>
                                    <th>Zona</th>
                                    <th>Direccion</th>
                                    <th>Marca</th>
                                    <th>Modelo</th>
                                    <th>Capacidad</th>
                                    <th>Electrocorrector</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Fecha de movimiento</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="medidor in medidores | orderBy:'NumeroEconomico'">
                                    <td>{{ medidor.NumeroEconomico }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Serie }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Holograma }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Sello }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Cuenta }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Zona }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Direccion }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Marca }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Modelo }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Capacidad }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Electrocorrector }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.Status }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ medidor.FechaMovimiento }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Deberias poner la sintaxis de consulta, para ver si se puede optimizar

Comment: lectura recomendada: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8274/slow-rendering-with-datatable

Comment: Hola podria poner tu codigo, para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: listo ahi esta el codigo que tengo

Comment: Recomendación en el server: Cuando tienes una consulta muy compleja, es preferible crear una vista en el SQL Server y ésta vista la trabajas como si fuera una tabla en el EF, de tal manera que tienes sólo un nivel al cual aplicar los filtros.

Comment: En el cliente: Primero vamos encontrando el problema de la lentitud: ¿Has intentado renderizar todos los elementos sin usar DataTable? ¿Pasa lo mismo? ¿Se puede aplicar el DataTable luego de haber renderizado todos los elementos?

Comment: Si, si pasa lo mismo al solo renderizar los registros sin el datatable

Comment: El EF también aumenta mucho el tiempo la primera vez que consultas, porque construye toda su estructura al inicio así sólo consultes un campo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu problema debe ser de renderizado ya que son mucho elementos que se crean de manera "dinámica", mi recomendación es que 'indexes' tu tabla, o sea que muestres los primeros 100 registros (ejemplo), tengan un botón de siguiente pagina,etc., cuando le den a siguiente renderizes las siguientes 100, ya que dudo que de alguna manera vayan a revisar los 5 mil registros de una sola o los vayan a comparar 'al ojo' los 5 mil al mismo tiempo.

espero ayudarte,saludos!

Comment: en efecto era un problema de renderizado, lo solucione haciendo un scroll infinito, gracias por contestar